# Unable to find WETH contract in mainnet fork

Tags: defi, alchemy, aave, goerli

I have created a fork of the ethereum mainnet using Alchemy. When I try to fetch the WETH contract in the fork, it says no contract deployed at the given address (0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2). However, when I do the same in Goerli testnet, I don't face any issues. Below is the code I use to test:

[image]

Below is the definition of the mainnet fork:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated as I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hi dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

How you forked it, you'll need to manually re-deploy the smart contracts that you want to interact with, which is not very practical.

Follow this simple tutorial to [fork the network using the Ganache CLI](https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/900001783063-Forking-an-EVM-compatible-mainnet-with-Ganache-CLI); this allows you to fork at a specific block.

Now you can point your framework to the new Ganache instance, allowing you to interact with contracts and data on the mainnet deterministically.